# Repeated application of union bound

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, cryptography

I was learning about probability theory, with different events, until I came across something I wanted to query.

[image]

I wanted to check if the above picture means if I pick **k = 3**, then:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As for *why*, consider a geometric interpretation:

[image]

The area contained in at least one of the sets (i.e. $\mathbb P(A \cup B \cup C)$) is no bigger than the sum of their individual areas (i.e. $\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) + \mathbb P(C)$).